# push() returning the length of items google app scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm having issues with some code.  I'm trying to add an element to the end of a 2d array, but the log is returning the length of the array.

```
var arr = [["a"],["b"],["c"],["d"]];
var arr2 = arr.push(["e"]);
Logger.log(arr2);
```

arr2 is returning "5" but would like it to return the array with the pushed element at the end of this array.

Comment: That's what the spec for `Array.prototype.push` dictates it should do. It mutates the original array and returns it's new length. I think what you're looking for is `arr.concat([ ["e"] ])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array, so you just need to log the initial array.

```js
var arr = [
  ["a"],
  ["b"],
  ["c"],
  ["d"]
];
arr.push(["e"]);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Values will be pushed in the same memory reference, return type of push method is integer, (length of the array)

Please do like this, your results will be achieved

```
var arr = [["a"],["b"],["c"],["d"]];
arr.push(["e"]);
Logger.log(arr);
```